# How do IMAP servers detect message end and response a APPEND completed?

Tags: imap

Interesting about how the server detect the end of client's message in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4315

As I know `multipart/mixed` contains a lot of empty lines, it would be wrong using just CRLF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages and similar multiline structures are preceded by a byte count.

```
> A1 APPEND INBOX {4082}\r\n
< + Go ahead\r\n
> (4082 bytes of message follow)\r\n
```

Simple as that.

Comment: You should read RFC3501 which outlines the basic IMAP protocol and command format, and includes this and other information.